# What is the JavaFX equivalent of this CSS linear gradient?

Tags: css, javafx, equivalent

.Spectrum {
    background-color: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb( 23,240,245) 0.000%,
                                              rgb(  5,  5,250) 20.000%,
                                              rgb(253,  5,245) 39.990%,
                                              rgb(253, 10, 23) 60.010%,
                                              rgb(248,250, 23) 80.000%,
                                              rgb( 17,233, 17) 100.000% );
}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nodes with style class "Spectrum" are instances of `Region` (which includes all layout panes and controls), then

```
.Spectrum {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to top right,  
         rgb( 23,240,245) 0.000%, 
         rgb( 5, 5,250) 20.000%, 
         rgb(253, 5,245) 39.990%, 
         rgb(253, 10, 23) 60.010%, 
         rgb(248,250, 23) 80.000%, 
         rgb( 17,233, 17) 100.000% );
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to use "to bottom right" which is closer to what I want. But it doesn't seem that the 135deg part is valid JavaFX-CSS